# GROUP BY MYSQL Performance

Tags: mysql

This is the query I'm trying to perform. While it works fine and delivers the information I need, the GROUP BY slows down the query.

```
    SELECT
            activations.id,
            activations.product, 
            activations.transaction_date AS activation_date, 
            activations.control_number, 
            activations.retail AS plan, 
            activations.account_number, 
            activations.invoice_date AS act_inv_date, 
            activations.invoice_number AS act_inv, 
            activations.commission_status, 
            commission1.settlement_date AS commission1_date, 
            commission1.total AS commission1_credit, 
            commission1.invoice_date AS commission1_inv_date, 
            commission1.invoice_number AS commission1_inv,
            commission2.settlement_date AS commission2_date, 
            commission2.total AS commission2_credit, 
            commission2.invoice_date AS commission2_inv_date, 
            commission2.invoice_number AS commission2_inv,
            payment1.transaction_date AS payment1_date,
            payment1.retail AS payment1_retail, 
            payment1.cost AS payment1_cost, 
            payment1.commission AS payment1_commission, 
            payment1.account_number AS payment1_account, 
            payment1.invoice_date AS payment1_inv_date, 
            payment1.invoice_number AS payment1_inv,
            payment2.transaction_date AS payment2_date,
            payment2.retail AS payment2_retail, 
            payment2.cost AS payment2_cost, 
            payment2.commission AS payment2_commission, 
            payment2.account_number AS payment2_account, 
            payment2.invoice_date AS payment2_inv_date, 
            payment2.invoice_number AS payment2_inv,
            payment3.transaction_date AS payment3_date,
            payment3.retail AS payment3_retail, 
            payment3.cost AS payment3_cost, 
            payment3.commission AS payment3_commission, 
            payment3.account_number AS payment3_account, 
            payment3.invoice_date AS payment3_inv_date, 
            payment3.invoice_number AS payment3_inv,
            spiff1.invoice_number AS spiff1_inv,
            spiff1.total AS spiff1_credit, 
            spiff1.invoice_date AS spiff1_inv_date,
            spiff2.invoice_number AS spiff2_inv,
            spiff2.total AS spiff2_credit, 
            spiff2.invoice_date AS spiff2_inv_date,
            spiff3.invoice_number AS spiff3_inv,
            spiff3.total AS spiff3_credit, 
            spiff3.invoice_date AS spiff3_inv_date
        FROM
        `commissions_debits` AS activations
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                commissions_credits AS commission1
            ON
                activations.control_number = commission1.control_number 
            AND 
                DATE(activations.transaction_date) = commission1.activation_date
            AND
                commission1.`type` = 'Commission'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                commissions_credits AS commission2
            ON
                activations.control_number = commission2.control_number 
            AND 
                DATE(activations.transaction_date) = commission2.activation_date
            AND
                commission2.id != commission1.id
            AND
                commission2.`type` = 'Commission'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                commissions_credits AS spiff1
            ON
                activations.control_number = spiff1.control_number
            AND 
                DATE(activations.transaction_date) = spiff1.activation_date     
            AND
                spiff1.`type` = 'Spiff'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                commissions_credits AS spiff2
            ON
                activations.control_number = spiff2.control_number
            AND 
                DATE(activations.transaction_date) = spiff2.activation_date     
            AND
                spiff2.`type` = 'Spiff'
            AND
                spiff2.id != spiff1.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                commissions_credits AS spiff3
            ON
                activations.control_number = spiff3.control_number
            AND 
                DATE(activations.transaction_date) = spiff3.activation_date     
            AND
                spiff3.`type` = 'Spiff'
            AND
                spiff3.id != spiff2.id
            AND
                spiff3.id != spiff1.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                commissions_debits AS payment1
            ON 
                activations.control_number = payment1.control_number
            AND 
                payment1.`type` = 'Payment'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                commissions_debits AS payment2
            ON 
                activations.control_number = payment2.control_number
            AND 
                payment2.`type` = 'Payment'
            AND
                payment2.id != payment1.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                commissions_debits AS payment3
            ON 
                activations.control_number = payment3.control_number
            AND 
                payment3.`type` = 'Payment'
            AND
                payment3.id != payment2.id
            AND
                payment3.id != payment1.id
        WHERE
            activations.`type` = 'Activation'
        AND
            activations.product != 'Simple SIM Act'
    GROUP BY
        activations.control_number
    ORDER BY
        activations.transaction_date
```

So this nets the following: 
Found rows: 46,780  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 9.431 sec

If I change the GROUP BY to activations.transaction_date it comes down to 4 sec, however I lose some valid rows.

Here are the creates for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `commissions_debits` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `settlement_date` DATE NOT NULL,
        `product` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `transaction_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
        `control_number` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `retail` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
        `discount` DECIMAL(9,4) NOT NULL,
        `cost` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
        `commission` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
        `account_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `invoice_date` DATE NOT NULL,
        `invoice_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `due_date` DATE NOT NULL,
        `commission_status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        INDEX `account_number` (`account_number`),
        INDEX `type` (`type`),
        INDEX `product` (`product`(255)),
        INDEX `transaction_date` (`transaction_date`),
        INDEX `control_number` (`control_number`),
        INDEX `id_type` (`id`, `type`),
        INDEX `type_product_control` (`type`, `product`(255), `control_number`),
        INDEX `invoice_number` (`invoice_number`)
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=116672
    ;

    CREATE TABLE `commissions_credits` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `settlement_date` DATE NOT NULL,
        `activation_date` DATE NOT NULL,
        `type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `item_description` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `control_number` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `dealer_code` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `debit` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
        `credit` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
        `tax` DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL,
        `total` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `account_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `invoice_date` DATE NOT NULL,
        `invoice_number` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        `due_date` DATE NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        INDEX `dealer_code` (`dealer_code`),
        INDEX `account_number` (`account_number`),
        INDEX `type` (`type`),
        INDEX `control_number` (`control_number`),
        INDEX `date_type` (`activation_date`, `type`),
        INDEX `date_id_type` (`activation_date`, `id`, `type`),
        INDEX `invoice_number` (`invoice_number`)
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=72568
    ;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
|| *id* || *select_type* || *table* || *type* || *possible_keys* || *key* || *key_len* || *ref* || *rows* || *Extra* ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || activations || ref || type,product,type_product_control || type || 302 || const || 50997 || Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || commission1 || ref || type,control_number,date_type,date_id_type || control_number || 47 || payst.activations.control_number || 1 ||  ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || commission2 || ref || type,control_number,date_type,date_id_type || control_number || 47 || payst.activations.control_number || 1 ||  ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || spiff1 || ref || type,control_number,date_type,date_id_type || control_number || 47 || payst.activations.control_number || 1 ||  ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || spiff2 || ref || type,control_number,date_type,date_id_type || control_number || 47 || payst.activations.control_number || 1 ||  ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || spiff3 || ref || type,control_number,date_type,date_id_type || control_number || 47 || payst.activations.control_number || 1 ||  ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || payment1 || ref || type,control_number,type_product_control || control_number || 47 || payst.activations.control_number || 1 ||  ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || payment2 || ref || type,control_number,type_product_control || control_number || 47 || payst.activations.control_number || 1 ||  ||
|| 1 || SIMPLE || payment3 || ref || type,control_number,type_product_control || control_number || 47 || payst.activations.control_number || 1 ||  ||
```

Maybe I can somehow improve the indices? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Selecting non-aggregate columns that aren't in a `GROUP BY` can lead to [unexpected results](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html).  Why are you only doing a `GROUP BY` on *just * `activations.control_number`?

Comment: What happens if there's more than 3 spiffs or more than 3 payments associated with the same activation?

Comment: I also strongly agree with the other commenters. Accessing a column in a `GROUP BY` query that is not aggregated and not part of the group statement itself will lead to undefined behaviour! read http://renormalize.org/post/24114561260/mysql-curious-features-non-deterministic-group-by

Comment: @Mr.Llama So I should be adding all of the selected columns to the `GROUP BY`? I've done some research and still don't quite understand non/aggregate columns. Nonetheless, I've done this and the query duration turned into 3 minutes. I really just need to remove the duplicate entries on the `control_number` column @Barmar Information on additional payments isn't required. 3 spiffs would be the max any activation would receive.

Answer (score 0):

as I see, `activations.control_number` has not index. Try to add index for that column then please notify me for negative or positive issues.

Comment: It does have an index.  `\`commissions_debits\` AS activations` and `INDEX \`control_number\` (\`control_number\`)`

Answer (score 0):

The execution plan looks fine, using a single index and `ref` type access for every join. No merge operations on multiple indexes, which is good too.

Note the `Using temporary` and `Using filesort` remarks.

**What does `Using temporary` mean?**

The data is too big to handle in memory, so a (computationally expensive) temporary table is created to perform your `SORT`. This is normal if you work with the default configuration of your server distribution. The innodb buffers are usually too small for grown and mature production databases. Play around with the [server parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-parameters.html) and [InnoDB parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-configuration-variables.html), if you can.

The important parameters here are:

- sort_buffer_size
- innodb_buffer_pool_size
- read_rnd_buffer_size

**What does `Using filesort` mean?**

The index used here (`control_number`) is not returning the rows in the order needed for your `SORT` and `GROUP` statements. You can improve the performance of those by using an index that is based on your `SORT` columns in the same order as given to the `SORT` statement.

One of these should do the trick:

```
INDEX `foo` (`control_number`, `transaction_date`)
INDEX `foo2` (`transaction_date`, `control_number`)
```

**[The manual says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html):**

> To increase ORDER BY speed, check whether you can get MySQL to use indexes rather than an extra sorting phase. If this is not possible, you can try the following strategies:
>
> - Increase the sort_buffer_size variable value.
> - Increase the read_rnd_buffer_size variable value.
> - Use less RAM per row by declaring columns only as large as they need to be to hold the values stored in them. For example, CHAR(16) is better than CHAR(200) if values never exceed 16 characters.
>
> Change the tmpdir system variable to point to a dedicated file system with large amounts of free space. The variable value can list several paths that are used in round-robin fashion; you can use this feature to spread the load across several directories. Paths should be separated by colon characters (“:”) on Unix and semicolon characters (“;”) on Windows, NetWare, and OS/2. The paths should name directories in file systems located on different physical disks, not different partitions on the same disk.

Comment: MYSQL 5.6 on a 4 core VPS with 4GB I set the following `innodb_buffer_pool_size=2GB
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
sort_buffer_size=4M
query_cache_size=512M
read_buffer_size=4M
thread_concurrency=16
table_cache=64` The query is still at the 8.5 second mark. This is the `EXPLAIN` extra column now `Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort ||`
I also added your recommended indices and cut the column lengths to minimums. Thanks